# Multiline regex doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

I'm trying to write a `commit-msg` hook for my `git` project that checks if commit message accord with a particular style guide. However, it looks like something works differently into the `bash` world regarding regexp. How could I accomplish my goal?

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

read -r -d '' pattern << EOM
(?x)                                      # Enable comments and whitespace insensitivity.
^                                         # Starting from the very beginning of the message
(feat|fix|docs|style|refactor|test|chore) # should be a type which might be one of the listed,
:[ ]                                      # the type should be followed by a colon and whitespace,
(.{1,50})\n                               # then goes a subject that is allowed to be 50 chars long at most,
(?:\n((?:.{0,80}\n)+))?                   # then after an empty line goes optional body each line of which
                                          # may not exceed 80 characters length.
$                                         # The body is considered everything until the end of the message.
EOM

message=$(cat "${1}")

if [[ ${message} =~ ${pattern} ]]; then
  exit 0
else
  error=$(tput setaf 1)
  normal=$(tput sgr0)
  echo "${error}The commit message does not accord with the style guide that is used on the project.${normal}"
  echo "For more details see https://udacity.github.io/git-styleguide/"
  exit 1
fi
```

I also tried writing this regexp in oneline, like as:

```bsh
pattern="^(feat|fix|docs|style|refactor|test|chore):[ ](.{1,50})\n(?:\n((?:.{0,80}\n)+))?$"
```

And even tryed replacing `\n` with `$'\n'` but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash supports POSIX extended regular expressions (ERE), not Perl-compatible regexes (PCRE). In particular, `(?x)` and `(?:...)` are PCRE.

On a quick look, the one-line version should work if you just replace `(?:...)` with `(...)`. The "ignore whitespace" function provided by Perl's `x` modifier isn't available in extended regexes.

See also: [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119905/170373)

Comment: Thank you @ilkkachu , I replaced non-capturing groups with capturing ones but it didn't help so I also replaced `\n` with `$'\n'` (`"^(feat|fix|docs|style|refactor|test|chore):"$'\s'"(.{1,50})"$'\n'"("$'\n'"((.{0,80}"$'\n'")+))?$"`). Now it works for multiline text inlined in variable when replace the `message` with an actual value but doesn't work with `message=$(cat ${file_name})`. Could you, please, advise on it?

Comment: Changed regexp to `"^(feat|fix|docs|style|refactor|test|chore):[ ](.{1,50})("$'\n'"("$'\n'"[^"$'\n'"]{0,80})+)?$"` - everything works fine now=)

Comment: @DenisVerhoturov, oh, sorry, I missed the `\n`. The command substitution in `message=$(cat filename)` would remove all trailing newlines from the value, which might affect your original regex